# "top" shows fail2ban and sshd at the very top, hogging CPU usage

Tags: server, security, cpu-load, fail2ban

`top` shows fail2ban and sshd at the very top and hogging CPU usage.

```
top - 19:30:57 up 1 day,  9:44,  1 user,  load average: 41.03, 41.02, 41.02
Tasks: 738 total,   1 running, 737 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 51.2 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 48.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 52827577+total, 51446102+free,  7173552 used,  6641224 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 51941568+avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2207 root      20   0 4656340   9756      4 S  4035  0.0  80861:59 sshd
35047 root      20   0  218824  15948   6044 S 100.0  0.0   0:54.47 fail2ban-server
35054 root      20   0   48688   4452   3396 R   5.9  0.0   0:00.03 top
    1 root      20   0   38136   6120   4016 S   0.0  0.0   0:54.93 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.28 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.07 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:27.60 rcu_sched
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.76 migration/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.22 watchdog/0

after that...
A lot of migration, watchdog, kworker...
```

When I came to the scene, the system was already there (meaning I didn't configure anything), and I am afraid to change files at random, even if I knew where to start.

I started with fail2ban.

`/var/log/fail2ban.log` shows a repetition of these lines, seems every minute.

```
timestamp,669 fail2ban.jail           [52316]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started
timestamp,997 fail2ban.server         [52402]: INFO    Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.9.3
timestamp,997 fail2ban.database       [52402]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
timestamp,001 fail2ban.jail           [52402]: INFO    Creating new jail 'sshd'
timestamp,005 fail2ban.jail           [52402]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' uses poller
timestamp,022 fail2ban.filter         [52402]: INFO    Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
timestamp,022 fail2ban.jail           [52402]: INFO    Initiated 'polling' backend
timestamp,035 fail2ban.actions        [52402]: INFO    Set banTime = 600
timestamp,036 fail2ban.filter         [52402]: INFO    Set maxRetry = 5
timestamp,037 fail2ban.filter         [52402]: INFO    Set findtime = 600
timestamp,039 fail2ban.filter         [52402]: INFO    Added logfile = /var/log/auth.log
timestamp,039 fail2ban.filter         [52402]: INFO    Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
timestamp,040 fail2ban.filter         [52402]: INFO    Set maxlines = 10
timestamp,114 fail2ban.server         [52402]: INFO    Jail sshd is not a JournalFilter instance
timestamp,128 fail2ban.jail           [52402]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started
timestamp,330 fail2ban.server         [52528]: INFO    Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.9.3
timestamp,330 fail2ban.database       [52528]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
timestamp,333 fail2ban.jail           [52528]: INFO    Creating new jail 'sshd'
timestamp,337 fail2ban.jail           [52528]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' uses poller
timestamp,355 fail2ban.filter         [52528]: INFO    Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
timestamp,355 fail2ban.jail           [52528]: INFO    Initiated 'polling' backend
timestamp,368 fail2ban.filter         [52528]: INFO    Set maxRetry = 5
timestamp,369 fail2ban.filter         [52528]: INFO    Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
timestamp,371 fail2ban.filter         [52528]: INFO    Added logfile = /var/log/auth.log
timestamp,371 fail2ban.filter         [52528]: INFO    Set findtime = 600
timestamp,372 fail2ban.actions        [52528]: INFO    Set banTime = 600
timestamp,372 fail2ban.filter         [52528]: INFO    Set maxlines = 10
timestamp,447 fail2ban.server         [52528]: INFO    Jail sshd is not a JournalFilter instance
timestamp,462 fail2ban.jail           [52528]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started
```

syslog file shows the following errors, over and over:

```
timestamp myserver fail2ban-client[29267]: ERROR  Unable to contact server. Is it running?
timestamp myserver systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
timestamp myserver systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Unit entered failed state.
timestamp myserver systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
timestamp myserver systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
timestamp myserver systemd[1]: Stopped Fail2Ban Service.
timestamp myserver systemd[1]: Starting Fail2Ban Service...
timestamp myserver fail2ban-client[29279]: timestamp,179 fail2ban.server         [29283]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.9.3
timestamp myserver fail2ban-client[29279]: timestamp,180 fail2ban.server         [29283]: INFO    Starting in daemon mode
timestamp myserver systemd[1]: Started Fail2Ban Service.
```

Also, `fail2ban-client status` shows this:

```
root@myserver:/var/log# fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:      1
`- Jail list:   sshd
```

Was my server compromised?
Or some bad actor(s) tried to infiltrate, and fail2ban worked, but worked too well, and something broke?

I read in this post, [How to reduce fail2ban memory usage](https://fmos.at/2009/05/15/how-to-reduce-fail2ban-memory-usage/) that I might want to use a `ulimit` parameter in `/etc/default/fail2ban`. That file is the default file; it seems no one has touched that file. I don't know if I should- it was working just fine without `ulimit -s 256` in that file.

How do I get the fail2ban-server and sshd off from the 'top'?

Only two people have root access, and both of us have not altered files or installed anything.

As I wrote in the comment section, I stopped sshd and fail2ban, then started, but the outcome has not changed. When I had stopped both services, they were gone from the output of `top`. Once I started them, they came back!

Please give some pointers.

Thank you.

PS: The server was restarted recently, and these problems came to surface.
I use key-based authentication now, but there was a 4-5 day window when the system used password authentication. Could it have been compromised during that interval?

```
sudo grep sshd.\*Failed /var/log/auth.log | less
```

shows about one hundred to about four hundred failed attempts during that period, depending on the day, but the `last` command does not show anyone that is not in our authorized list, so I would like to believe that the server has not been compromised. I hope I am right :)

PPS: We are (still) using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-138-generic x86_64)!

Comment: Can you Kill _HUP the process and see if it restarts normally. Or I would stop and restart it. Can you see where the ssh attempts are coming from? Is the server frozen?

Comment: I only get 'creating new jail' when fail2ban starts up. If you are getting that constantly, something is wrong. Consider adding some fail2ban.log to your question.

Comment: @Organic Marble: I added some fail2ban.log. Thanks.

Comment: It appears that your fail2ban is crashing and restarting every two minutes.   The part of the log you posted shows a normal startup. The interesting part in the log would be when it crashes.

Comment: I should point out the failed attempts part is a bad thing.  You should be whitelisting access to your SSH endpoint, notjust blindly accepting SSH connections.

Comment: @Mark Scheck: You mean kill -HUP <processID>, say 2207 for sshd and 35047 for fail2ban? I am working remotely. Would it (2207, pID for sshd) kill my ssh connection? I would be in trouble if I have no access to the server. The failed ssh attempts are from attackers, plain and simple. The server is not frozen. Thanks.

Comment: @Organic Marble: Any keywords I might be looking for? In which file would it in? Because the fail2ban.log only has that information repeatedly. Do you suggest I change fail2ban.config log level to something else (Choices are CRITICAL, ERROR, WARNING, NOTICE, INFO and DEBUG)?

Comment: @Thomas Ward: I "generally" have private/public key-based authentication, so I don't worry about ssh- or, at least, I didn't worry until now! This 4-5 day window, we had to "open" the server for password-based authentication, now it is back to key-based. Do you mean some other ways to make it more secure? Thanks.

Comment: @user14045797 yes, I mean deny all port 22 connections *except* from trusted IP addresses (such as yours or the IP addresses your administrative users use, or your workplace IP range if you have a specific IP range in use at the workplace).  NEVER leave port 22 just 'open' to the world.

Comment: I've never actually had fail2ban crash so I am not sure where to look for diagnostic information.

Comment: @Mark Scheck: I took a leap of faith (!), and stopped and started both ssh and fail2ban. Faith because I am still learning the ropes. result: No change! 

As a side note, grateful to that person or people who designed the ssh so that a current ssh session is not disconnected even if the ssh service is restarted or stopped and started.

Comment: @Thomas Ward: Sorry, my explanation was inadequate. We use a port different than 22. But your point about filtering based on IP is taken. Office politics will oppose that though. Still, something to keep in mind!

Comment: @Zanna: Thanks for formatting, and tagging! Looks much better.

Comment: :) no problem! I wish I could help with your issue!