# Very high load even nothing is done

Tags: server, performance, top, fail2ban

I have the below Ubuntu server hosted by a commercial hoster. The hoster says he has no clue.
Attached a screenshot from `top` where can be seen which processes are slowing down the server.
It's more or less always `fail2ban-server` and `mysqld` - even there are no queries running. I can say the server is *sleeping*.

[image]

What can it be, what can I improve? The server doesn't respond for minutes and after a while the load decreases to almost 0. I can say, this repeats like a sort of *waves*.

Dump from `/etc/os-release`

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=impish
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.10"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 21.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="21.10"
VERSION="21.10 (Impish Indri)"
VERSION_CODENAME=impish
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=impish
```

---

As requested, the `var/log/fail2ban.log`

```
2022-05-25 10:02:59,011 [466]: INFO    [sshd] Found 117.50.* - 2022-05-25 10:02:59
2022-05-25 10:04:09,378 [466]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 141.98.* - 2022-05-25 10:04:09
2022-05-25 10:04:14,324 [466]: INFO    [sshd] Found 117.50.* - 2022-05-25 10:04:14
2022-05-25 10:05:21,666 [466]: INFO    [sshd] Found 117.50.* - 2022-05-25 10:05:21
2022-05-25 10:06:28,512 [466]: INFO    [sshd] Found 117.50.* - 2022-05-25 10:06:28
2022-05-25 10:06:29,031 fail2ban.actions        [466]: WARNING [sshd] 117.50.* already banned
2022-05-25 10:07:35,495 [466]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 45.125.* - 2022-05-25 10:07:35
2022-05-25 10:07:39,914 [466]: INFO    [sshd] Found 117.50.* - 2022-05-25 10:07:39
2022-05-25 10:08:45,731 [466]: INFO    [sshd] Found 117.50.* - 2022-05-25 10:08:45
2022-05-25 10:09:58,390 [466]: INFO    [sshd] Found 117.50.* - 2022-05-25 10:09:58
2022-05-25 10:10:55,980 [466]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 185.36.81.192 - 2022-05-25 10:10:55
2022-05-25 10:11:04,588 [466]: INFO    [sshd] Found 117.50.* - 2022-05-25 10:11:03
2022-05-25 10:12:15,655 [466]: INFO    [sshd] Found 117.50.* - 2022-05-25 10:12:15
2022-05-25 10:12:15,846 fail2ban.actions        [466]: WARNING [sshd] 117.50.* already banned
2022-05-25 10:22:15,401 fail2ban.actions        [466]: NOTICE  [sshd] Unban 117.50.*
2022-05-25 10:23:20,222 [466]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 141.98.* - 2022-05-25 10:23:19
2022-05-25 10:26:20,459 [466]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 141.98.* - 2022-05-25 10:26:20
2022-05-25 10:31:19,095 [466]: WARNING [sshd] Simulate NOW in operation since found time has too large deviation 1653474410.0 ~ 1653474679.0946503 +/- 60
2022-05-25 10:31:19,144 [466]: WARNING [webmin-auth] Simulate NOW in operation since found time has too large deviation 1653474410.0 ~ 1653474679.1440747 +/- 60
2022-05-25 10:31:19,220 [466]: WARNING [webmin-auth] Please check jail has possibly a timezone issue. Line with odd timestamp: May 25 10:26:50 *** gnome-keyring-daemon[1064]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/2, but it's already registered
2022-05-25 10:31:19,220 [466]: WARNING [sshd] Please check jail has possibly a timezone issue. Line with odd timestamp: May 25 10:26:50 *** gnome-keyring-daemon[1064]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/2, but it's already registered
2022-05-25 10:32:45,859 [466]: WARNING [postfix] Simulate NOW in operation since found time has too large deviation 1653474686.0 ~ 1653474765.8594735 +/- 60
2022-05-25 10:32:46,309 [466]: WARNING [postfix-sasl] Simulate NOW in operation since found time has too large deviation 1653474686.0 ~ 1653474766.3090467 +/- 60
2022-05-25 10:32:46,483 [466]: WARNING [postfix-sasl] Please check jail has possibly a timezone issue. Line with odd timestamp: May 25 10:31:26 *** postfix/anvil[265867]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:141.98.10.27) at May 25 10:23:17
2022-05-25 10:32:46,309 [466]: WARNING [dovecot] Simulate NOW in operation since found time has too large deviation 1653474686.0 ~ 1653474766.3098185 +/- 60
2022-05-25 10:32:46,483 [466]: WARNING [postfix] Please check jail has possibly a timezone issue. Line with odd timestamp: May 25 10:31:26 *** postfix/anvil[265867]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:141.98.10.27) at May 25 10:23:17
2022-05-25 10:32:46,567 [466]: WARNING [dovecot] Please check jail has possibly a timezone issue. Line with odd timestamp: May 25 10:31:26 *** postfix/anvil[265867]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:141.98.10.27) at May 25 10:23:17
2022-05-25 10:39:03,132 [466]: INFO    [postfix-sasl] Found 45.125.* - 2022-05-25 10:36:39
2022-05-25 10:39:52,799 [466]: INFO    [sshd] Found 42.200.* - 2022-05-25 10:39:52
```

Comment: Related: ["top" shows fail2ban and sshd at the very top, hogging CPU usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278596/top-shows-fail2ban-and-sshd-at-the-very-top-hogging-cpu-usage). Please include your log: `/var/log/fail2ban.log`.

Comment: Also, suggestion to clean out the fail2ban database: [How to stop Fail2ban from causing high CPU usage](https://thisinterestsme.com/fail2ban-high-cpu-usage/).

Comment: Did you try cleaning the database, and/or rotating all logs? These are other suggestions I see popping up..

Comment: @ArturMeinild Cleaning the database didn't help. I am now figuring out how to rotate the logs. I stopped now the service.

Comment: This is almost certainly the result of I/O constraints. Depending on the amount of traffic you're receiving, you may need to examine/tweak the indexes in your Fail2ban database. If the indexes are larger than the memory you have available, your system will spend most of its time working with the storage medium ...

Comment: @matigo The server is doing nothing. There is **no traffic**! I changed the port from 22 to some high number and left`fail2ban` stopped.